# Do labels order effects search time?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 2.1.7 Recently i was experimenting with Match queries, searching for nodes with several labels. And i found out, that generally query

```
Match (p:A:B) return count(p) as number
```

and

```
Match (p:B:A) return count(p) as number
```

works different time, extremely in cases when you have for example 2 millions of Nodes A and 0 of Nodes B. 
So do labels order effects search time? Is this future is documented anywhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neo4j internally maintains a labelscan store - that's basically a lookup to quickly get all nodes carrying a definied label `A`.

When doing a query like

```
MATCH (n:A:B) return count(n)
```

labelscanstore is used to find all `A` nodes and then they're filtered if those nodes carry label `B` as well. If `n(A) >> n(B)` it's way more efficient to do `MATCH (n:B:A)` instead since you look up only a few `B` nodes and filter those for A.

You can use `PROFILE MATCH (n:A:B) return count(n)` to see the query plan. For Neo4j <= 2.1.x you'll see a different query plan depending on the order of the labels you've specified.

Starting with Neo4j 2.2 (milestone M03 available as of writing this reply) there's a cost based Cypher optimizer. Now Cypher is aware of node statistics and they are used to optimize the query.

As an example I've used the following statements to create some test data:

```
create (:A:B);
with 1 as a foreach (x in range(0,1000000)  | create (:A));
with 1 as a foreach (x in range(0,100)  | create (:B));
```

We have now 100 B nodes, 1M A nodes and 1 AB node. In 2.2 the two statements:

```
MATCH (n:B:A) return count(n)
MATCH (n:A:B) return count(n)
```

result in the exact same query plan (and therefore in the same execution speed):

```
+------------------+---------------+------+--------+-------------+---------------+
|         Operator | EstimatedRows | Rows | DbHits | Identifiers |         Other |
+------------------+---------------+------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| EagerAggregation |             3 |    1 |      0 |    count(n) |                       |
|           Filter |            12 |    1 |     12 |           n | hasLabel(n:A) |
|  NodeByLabelScan |            12 |   12 |     13 |           n |            :B |
+------------------+---------------+------+--------+-------------+---------------+
```

Since there are only few `B` nodes, it's cheaper to scan for B's and filter for `A`. Smart Cypher, isn't it ;-)

Comment: Great answer.  With the upcoming cost-based planner, will this change?  Will the optimizer be able to do it the other way if it's faster?

Comment: It actually does it in 2.2.0-M03 - just checked it.

Comment: In 2.2.10 the order of the labels still matter for cypher queries. My local test produced quite different amounts of db hits: 27509335 != 111913